# Covert ActiveRecord MySQL result to array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

When I run this line `@users = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(raw)` I get a mysql result back which I don't feel is as clean or easy to use as a result of actual user objects. Is there a way to covert this result into a array of class `User` objects? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
@users = User.find_by_sql( ["SELECT * FROM users ..."])
```